# Accessing Component Object in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I created a component object like this in page1.cfm, to call one of the cfc's functions: IsDigits:

```
<CFSET MyObj = New cfcomponents.MyComp.RecordValidation(Trim(session.userid)
                               ,Trim(session.yr))>

<CFSET MyObj.IsDigits(st_SSN_and_BDates)>
```

After page1.cfm is finished processing, it goes to page2.cfm using:

```
<script>
    window.location="page2.cfm
</script>
```

(I can't use cflocation because of cfflush that I use on almost every page).

In page2.cfm, I still need to call different functions that exist in the RecordValidation.cfc. I'm wondering if I have to run

```
<CFSET MyObj = New cfcomponents.MyComp.RecordValidation
```

... one more time?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't instantiate the object into a session variable?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware I can do that. I may have to use application scope instead? Thanks

Comment: Only store them in a shared scope if the functions are stateless. Otherwise, you will have threading problems. But I am curious about why you say "have to".  Like Adam mentioned, your description suggests you *believe* there is some problem with creating objects multiple times - but have not explained why you think that way. Hard to say if it is there really is a problem or not without more information.

Answer (score 2):

There's no limit to how many times one can create objects. If you need another one in the next request... create another one!

Do you perhaps need to elaborate on the problem you're perceiving you're having, so we can give you a more exacting answer?

Also perhaps look into using something like [DI/1](https://github.com/framework-one/di1) or [WireBox](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/WireBox.cfm) to manage your objects more strategically? It depends on your requirements as to whether something like that will help you.